# Fortnite does your tier reset or lock after the end of the season?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I purchased the season 3 pass and am currently at tier 85.  I would like to know if I keep my current tier progression even after the season is over.  Will I still be able to unlock the last skin of the season 3 pass when season 4 starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once season 3 ends and 4 starts, you can no longer make any tier progression for season 3 and would no longer be able to unlock the last skin through tier progression.

This is based off how previous seasons have worked.

**Can now confirm with the start of season 4 you can no longer make tier progression for season 3**

Comment: I was indeed waiting for season 4 to start before committing the answer.